# Combining functions

Tags: calculus

I want to know how to represent functions by one formula which are defined by multiple formula.
For example:

The function $f(x)$ defined as follows

$$f(x)=x,0\leq x< 1 \text{ and } f(x)=2x-1,1\leq x\leq2$$

could be represented as $$f(x)=\frac{3}{2}(x-\frac{1}{3})+\frac{1}{2}|x-1|$$

Then, I was working on the following function
$$ f(y)=y^2-5y,0<y\leq6, \text{ and } f(y)=-y^2-5y,-6<y \leq0$$

I wanted to know is there a method using which such functions could be combined to a single formula

Answer (score 1):

In that particular example
$$
f(y)=|y|(y-5).
$$
With the new formulation, we have 
$$
f(y)=y\,|y|-5\,y.
$$

Comment: I am sorry I have made a correction $f(y)=-5y-y^2$